# What's the meaning for the math symbol in the picture?

Tags: math

I saw a paper with a special symbol in the below, however I don't the meaning for it.

[image]

https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/comjnl/53/6/10.1093/comjnl/bxp031/2/bxp031.pdf?Expires=1487170756&Signature=YmfmVlAdHIFDdWF6vzenjnP8SRbKdeilhY9SKYVJlrd3BMpKn6M353JAA6vNqZ8nduIGu4FHQizWjRWMeN2KoFa8uAFnc0iJJt6UjR6Yx-3XuOmvP0eCb-9ufR0zwBltRD6RTxgwRsZ6q5v3~bc-rmp8MotTOYtRvaM2Q2yH1pJZ8RrBFAvJO1JXbsFAnM1CYhfK1MR1sfh7LaWNGR5tK9C5ifCF~fGRByqRZPRMtUgdrsZYrZVbHuwPheFB-42QVsK7Em0dWs8B896jkBMythAnGad03u3QX108Wo10PlorsEem9CEJ-XbkvnC5yj-HU8I30kkC42WpRizLUJPMmw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It is a paper about JVM mechanism , it is  absolutely to do with programming.

Comment: The answer IS in the definition you've posted. It could be any other symbol, but this one intuitively associates with a partial order.

Comment: If the paper were about some other mathematical area, your question wouldn't change.  Therefore, your question doesn't really depend on JVM mechanism.  Therefore, it is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Definition 5.1 (Galois Connection/Insertion). Let (C, ⊆)
>   and (A, ⊑) be two complete lattices. [...]

⊑ denotes the order relation for lattice A.